$100$ people, among whom are A and B, are lined up randomly. Variance of the number of all people who are behind A and B. Need solution verification
$100$ people, among whom are A and B, are lined up randomly. Let $X$ denote the number of all people who are behind A and behind B. Determine the variance of the variable $X$.

People A and B can take any place in line, and $X$ represents the number of people behind both of them.
If person A stands at position $i$ and person B stands at position $j$, the people behind both of them are those who stand at positions greater than $max(i,j)$. Assuming $i \leq j$, the variable $X$ takes on the value $n-j$, where $n=100$. Hence:
$$X = 100 − max(i,j)$$
Therefore:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[100 − max(i,j)] = 100 − \mathbb{E}[ max(i,j)]$$
For two people, the number of possible combinations of positions $i$ and $j$ is ${100}\choose{2}$. For a given maximum position $k$, the number of combinations where $max(i,j)=k$ is $k-1$ (one person is in position $k$ and the other is in one of the $k-1$ previous positions). Therefore:
$$\mathbb{P}(max(i,j)=k)= \frac{k-1}{{100}\choose{2}} = \frac{2(k-1)}{100 \cdot 99}$$
$$\mathbb{E}[max(i,j)]= \sum_{k=1}^{100} k \cdot \mathbb{P}(max(i,j)=k)= \sum_{k=1}^{100} k \cdot \frac{2(k-1)}{100 \cdot 99} = \frac{2}{100 \cdot 99} \sum_{k=1}^{100} (k^2 - k)$$
Here we know that:

$\sum_{k=1}^{100} k^2 = \frac{100 \cdot 101 \cdot 201}{6} = 338350$
$\sum_{k=1}^{100} k = \frac{100 \cdot 101}{2} = 5050$

Therefore:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = 100 - \frac{2}{100 \cdot 99}(338350 - 5050) = 32.67$$
Now the variance:
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ X^2 \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ (100 − max(i,j))^2 \right]$$
$$X^2 = ( 100 − max(i,j) )^2 = 10000 − 200max(i,j) + (max(i,j))^2 $$
So:
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[10000−200max(i,j)+(max(i,j))^2] = 10000 − 200 \mathbb{E}[max(i,j)] + \mathbb{E}[(max(i,j))^2]$$
From that:
$$\mathbb{E}[(max(i,j))^2] = \sum_{k=1}^{100}​ k^2 \cdot \mathbb{P}(max(i,j)=k)= \frac{2}{100 \cdot 99} \sum_{k=1}^{100} (k^3 − k^2)$$
Here we know that:

$\sum_{k=1}^{100} k^3 = \left( \frac{100 \cdot 101}{2} \right)^2 = 25502500$

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 10000 − 200⋅67.33 + \frac{2}{99 \cdot 100} (25502500−338350) = 10000 − 13466 + 5083.33 = 1617.33$$
Finally:
$$Var(X) = E[X^2] − (E[X])^2 = 1617.33 − (32.67)^2 = 1617.33 − 1067.11 = 550.22$$
Does it look correct? Is there any easier way to calculate that?

Well, you may skip a bit of calculation by noting that $\mathsf {Var}(a+bZ)=b^2\mathsf{Var}(Z)$ for any constants $a,b$ and random variable $Z$:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(X) &=\mathsf{Var}(100-\max\{i,j\})\\&=\mathsf {Var}(\max\{i,j\})\\&=\mathsf E(\max\{i,j\}^2)-\mathsf E(\max\{i,j\})\\&=\dfrac{2}{9900}\sum_{k=2}^{100}(k^3-k^2)-\left(\dfrac{2}{9900}\sum_{k=2}^{100}(k^2-k)\right)^2\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$
Also, the lower bound of the series should be $2$ because the maximum placement of two values cannot be $1$.   Fortunately, this does not affect the summation because the terms equal zero at $k=1$.
